# Code for picking out even and odd numbers from a list and then adding them to seperate lists

Tags: python

I tried to write a code for picking out even and odd numbers from a list and then listing them on another list. But the code is not running completely as it stops after 3 iterations, can any one help me out.

```
nums = [] 
even = []
odd = []
for i in range(5): 
    num = int(input('Give me a number:      ')) 
    nums.append(num) 
 
for x in (nums):
    y = nums.pop()
    if y%2==0:
        even.append(x)
    else:
        odd.append(x)
print('the odd number are ', odd,'the even number are ',even)
```

After running that code i was only able to get 3 iterations when i provided 5 succesive numbers. but when i provided random 5 numbers, the numbers where listed out randomly.
input:
Give me a number:               1
Give me a number:               2
Give me a number:               3
Give me a number:               4
Give me a number:               5

output:
the odd number are  [5, 3] the even number are  [4]

Comment: In your loop, `x` is GIVING you the numbers one at a time.  You do NOT need to pop the values.  When you do `nums.pop()`, you are changing the list so the `for` statement gets the wrong ones.  Just delete the `y = nums.pop()` and change the `y` to `x`.

Comment: no need of `nums.pop()`.

Comment: In your code, y isn't needed and you're altering a container as you iterate it. I would have used itertools.tee and filter, but your lists probably aren't big enough for that to matter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

```
even = []
odd = []

for _ in range(5):
    num = int(input('Give me a number:      '))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even.append(num)
    else:
        odd.append(num)

print('the odd number are ', odd, 'the even number are ', even)
```

output:

```
Give me a number:      1
Give me a number:      2
Give me a number:      3
Give me a number:      4
Give me a number:      5
the odd number are  [1, 3, 5] the even number are  [2, 4]
```

[Update]
If you want to take all the input at once in a single line:

```
even = []
odd = []

input_data = [int(i) for i in input('enter the comma-separated numbers: ').split(',')]
# print(input_data)
for i in input_data:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(i)
    else:
        odd.append(i)

print('the odd number are ', odd, 'the even number are ', even)
```

output:

```
enter the comma-separated numbers: 1,2,3,4,5
the odd number are  [1, 3, 5] the even number are  [2, 4]
```

Comment: is there a way for me to provide all the input at once?

Comment: yes, you can take the input all at once in one line using the same input() function. It'll be a string datatype and then you can split the input string let's say across commas or space depending on how you separated the input values while taking the input. The split() will return a list data type containing all the input values as list items. I'll update it in the above answer.

Comment: separating the tasks allows you to easily change the way you take input and allows you to unit test your splitter function